# Question about the new Mac App Store

Tags: macos, app-store

Mac Store wasn't released yet, but I know that are experienced mac programmers here and I'm wondering if an app (that is additional to an iPhone app) can be posted as free without restrictions (the app itself is not useful without the iPhone app). Someone knows about it?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think you might need to rephrase your question. I'm not sure what you're asking. What do you mean by "... additional to an iPhone app?" You mean an application, that itself needs another application in order to "be useful?"

Comment: I cant see why not, several apps do it already (Ipad scrabble etc)

Comment: It would appear to be possible from prior art, but do pay attention to the publicly posted "don't" list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fact that there are experienced Mac programmers here is not really relevant — since you're asking about App Store rules, experience developing outside the App Store doesn't shed any light on the subject.

But since it's allowed on the iPhone, and there's no evidence that it would be disallowed in the Mac App Store, it probably would be fine.

But since anyone interested in the app would already have to have the iPhone app, it doesn't really matter if it's allowed in the Mac App Store. The Mac allows users to run arbitrary applications, so you can just give them an address to download it from.

Comment: Thanks very much for your answer, Chuck. Sorry for confusion. I never developed a Mac app, and thought that after the release of Mac App Store, one thing could be tied to another (i.e. cannot have Mac apps without Mac App Store).